Remote-Debugging App deployed on Tomcat in Docker Container "Connection Reset"
When trying to debug an App deployed on an Tomcat Applicationserver running in a Docker Container, the connection is getting reset when attaching to the remote JVM.
How do I get the Remote-Debugger to attach to the Remote JVM?
The API-Endpoint created is working fine - the expected result is being returned.
The Conainer is built using folloing Dockerfile:
FROM tomcat

COPY target/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

ENV JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"

CMD ["catalina.sh", "jpda", "run"]

The Container is then stared using the following script:
#!/bin/bash

docker run -e JPDA_ADDRESS=8000 \
           -p 8080:8080 \
           -p 8000:8000 \
           --name demo \
           pol/demo:latest \
           catalina.sh jpda run

Checking if the port is opened correctly with $ docker ps :

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
124b485072a1   pol/demo:latest   "catalina.sh jpda run"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   demo

Testing the port using telnet, the result is:
$ telnet localhost 8000                                                                                                                                                                                 

Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.


Tomcat Logs:
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
...
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
27-Oct-2024 11:38:10.415 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp

I tried to reference multiple guides on the internet, dontpanicblog in particular, none helped, same result every time.
For further information, my IntelliJ remote config looks like this:

My Java-Version:
openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.2+13 (build 21.0.2+13-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.2+13 (build 21.0.2+13-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)


